# Selenium C# displaying custom exceptions if booleans marked false?

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests

I am coding a selenium test case to verify all elements are present on a web page and Im fairly green at coding so bear with me here.  I have boolean vars set up for each element and if not found, I mark them false.  At the end of my code/test, I want to display custom exceptions for each false boolean encountered.  What's the easiest way to go about this?

```
if (!headerLogoPresent || !headerMsgDropPresent || !headerMsgDropSubGeneralPresent || !headerUserDropPresent || !headerUserDropSubProfilePresent ||
            !headerUserDropSubCredentialsPresent || !headerUserDropSubSettingsPresent || !headerUserDropSubChgPassPresent || !headerUserDropSubRstGridPresent ||
            !headerUserDropSubLogOffPresent || !headerSupportDropPresent || !headerSupportDropSubBasePresent || !headerSupportDropSubFaqPresent || !headerSupportDropSubTicketPresent
            || !emailTextInputFieldPresent || !saveButPresent || !bodyTextProfilePresent || !bodyTextEmailPresent || !bodyTextCopyrightPresent)
        {
            //then throw custom exception for each variable marked false;
        }
```

Comment: Make a `List` of the value of the `booleans` and then iterate over the list in a `foreach` loop to capture the false values...?  Are you writing the exceptions to the `Console` or a log file?

Comment: I was just planning on using "throw new Exception("Custom Message")"

Comment: You can also make a class with `Name`, `IsPresent` and `ExceptionMessage` properties. Put it in alist as @Brian suggested and loop throw it. It the error messages are different this will be pretty helpful.